# erb & HTML, what should I name input is, name, and value?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I haven't programmed in a few years and I'm creating a small quiz to help me drill some vocab terms for schoolwork.

[image: The quiz will look like this]

In my file quiz.erb, I have the following:

<%= question %>

" type="text" name="<%= @name %>" value="<%= @value %>" />

In my main file, it_quiz.rb, I have the questions laid out like this (I'm using Sinatra, by the way):

```
get '/' do
  @title = 'Italian Quiz'
  @questions = Hash.new
  @questions["a dog"] = ["un cane"]
  @questions["a cat"] = ["un gatto"]
  @questions["hello"] = ["ciao", "salve"]
  @id, @name, @value =
  erb :quiz
end
```

As you can see, I don't have @id, @name, or @value set to anything. What should I set it to? This project may be a bit over my head, (and I know there are plenty of quiz programs out there that would suffice), but I would really like to learn this.

Comment: Can you show the expected HTML?

Comment: Here is the repo for the project with everything I've got so far:
https://github.com/MelanieS/IQ

Comment: Your goal is to present several solutions to yourself and select which one is best (as in multiple choice)? Or to fill in the inputs and compare to the expected answer?

Comment: Fill in the input (blank form) and compare to expected answer. I apologize for not being super clear. :S

Comment: It's only confusing b/c the RHS of the hash assignments is an array, which makes it seem like there can be multiple answers, otherwise I would have assumed it was like the image.

Comment: Ideally, for something like "hello", entering either "ciao" or "salve" would result in a correct answer. Only one needs to be entered, not both. I see what you mean with the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melanie,

Glad you're working on this, it's always encouraging to me when I see beginners challenging themselves to learn more and solve their own problems with code.

I thought about it a bit, and decided the best way to answer this was with a video, because there's some context and thoughts that went into some of the decisions, so I thought it would be more helpful if they were captured. This makes the answer less generally useful (people can't quickly scan some text to find an answer), but it's a pretty specific question anyway, and so it will probably only be helpful to people in a very similar situation to yours, which means the video is probably more helpful for them, too.

**The [changes](https://github.com/JoshCheek/IQ.git) are on github.**

**[Here](https://vimeo.com/49660128) is the video.**

If the stuff where I made classes is beyond what you're familiar with, then you might find [Ruby Kickstart](http://ruby-kickstart.com/) useful, it's a site I made to teach Ruby to beginners (it might move a bit fast for beginners, but given your question, I'd expect you have have the capacity and tenacity to follow along). It's free, all the materials are open source and easily accessible.

It also looks like you're in Chicago, we have a rich Ruby community here in Chicago:

- you can always come out to the [ChicagoRuby](http://www.meetup.com/ChicagoRuby/) events (especially the hack nights) and ask someone for help or feedback.
- We have [Code and Coffee](https://twitter.com/mikelikesbikes/status/247806316725288961) every Tuesday morning, which I go to when I can wake up that early (less often than I'd like to admit) It's unstructured, but the people are friendly and happy to help.
- I'm also giving a [talk](http://8th-light.gathers.us/events/8lu-understand-all-the-things-recipes-for-responsive-feedback) on Nov 28th that is aimed at people around your level of experience, it's about how to get effective feedback, so you can solve problems like these.

Hope this helps you. Keep at it, you're doing well and coding is among the most rewarding things you can learn :)

Comment: Wow! Just logged in to see this! Thank you so much! I will definitely check out ChicagoRuby! :)

Answer (score 1):

From what you are doing, I believe you are wanting to populate params for Sinatra to use in your view, after you evaluate the answers for the results.  So, for id, perhaps the index of the questions would be appropriate.  You will likely change your code to show each.with_index or each_with_index so that you can get that value assigned.

You are also free to use other things rather than name and value as names as well.  It is your form, create them as you wish to communicate your code.

I will not speculate past that from what you have so far though.